# onclick of cell css make that block yellow

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

.[see js bin](http://jsbin.com/icizem/2/edit)

if i drag on minute 15 to 45 then name john having csstdgreen then i have i  to make john block yellow.
  if i drag on minute 15 to 30 then jary having csstdgreen then i have i  to make jary block yellow.
 i drag on minute 15 then jack having csstdgreen then i have i  to make jack block yellow.
  only one at a time.How can i do that with jquery

i have shown an exmple here i have to do like this [see demo](http://jsbin.com/eritud/edit#javascript,html,live)

```
$(".csstdgreen").live('mousedown', function (e)
                {
                    //This line gets the index of the first clicked row.
                    lastRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
                    $(this).removeClass("csstdgreen").addClass("csstdyellow");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
                $(document).live('mouseup', function () { flag = false; });
                $(".csstdgreen").live('mouseenter', function (e)
                {
                    // Compares with the last and next row index.
                    currentRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
                    if (lastRow == currentRow || lastRow == currentRow - 1 || lastRow == currentRow + 1)
                    {
                        lastRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
                    } else
                        return;

                    if (flag)
                    {
                        $(this).children(":not(:first)").addClass("csstdyellow");
                        e.preventDefault();
                        flag = false;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are looking for something like this?

```
$('td').click(function() { // <-- on a td click
    if ($(this).hasClass('csstdgreen')) { // <-- check if current clicked element has this class
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow'); // <-- if it does the change background color
    }
});​
```

Also don't forget to wrap your code inside a document.ready function so it waits for the dom to load before trying to look for your elements in the dom.
http://jsfiddle.net/64Byz/

Comment: I have to drag on 15,30,45 cell if and only if having csstdgreen.then make it cell yellow by dragging  see my jquery code

Comment: See i giving u exmple when i click on jary then i have to make whole jerry block yellow see like this http://jsbin.com/eritud/edit#javascript,html,live How can i do that like same for john and jack

Answer (score 0):

your code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".csstr").click(function(){ 
        $(".csstr").removeClass('csstdyellow').addClass('csstdgreen');
        var current_cls = $(this).attr('rel');      
        $('.' + current_cls + ' > td').removeClass('csstdgreen');
        $('.' + current_cls).addClass('csstdyellow');
    });
});
</script>
```

I made some changes your html to achieve this. I added the extra attribute "rel" and extra class to every row that we want to change. Its compulsion that "rel" value and added class name should be same. for example you want to change the color of all rows related with "john" then you have to add rel="cls1" and class="cls1" (if another class already added in row then add new class like class="csstr cls1") in every rows of john.

```
<table border="1">
<tr class="csstr cls1" rel="cls1" >
<td class="csstdgreen">
    15

</td>
<td class="csstdgreen" rowspan="3">
    john
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="csstr cls1" rel="cls1">
<td class="csstdgreen">
    30
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="csstr cls1" rel="cls1">
<td class="csstdgreen "> 
    45
</td>
</tr>
    <tr  class="csstr cls2" rel="cls2">
      <td class="csstdgreen ">15</td>
      <td class="csstdgreen " rowspan="2">Jary</td>
    </tr>
      <tr class="csstr cls2" rel="cls2">
      <td class="csstdgreen ">30</td>      
    </tr>
     <tr class="csstr cls3" rel="cls3">
      <td class="csstdgreen">15</td>
      <td class="csstdgreen" rowspan="1">Jack</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: See i giving u exmple when i click on jary then i have to make whole jerry block yellow see like this http://jsbin.com/eritud/edit#javascript,html,live How can i do that like same for john and jack

Comment: Shahid its impossible to achieve with my html in jsbin without any edit to tr class because the html i write in server side.

Answer (score 0):

i change your HTML because from your given HTML we can't achieve what you want...

i write javascript as

```
  $(document).ready(function()
              {

                $('.csstdgreen').click(function(){
                 $('.csstdgreen').removeClass('csstdyellow'); 
                  $(this).closest('table').find('td').addClass("csstdyellow");
               });
       });
```

and your updated code with HTML is on

http://jsbin.com/icaluy/36/edit#source

and if you want to occur this on mouse over then follow this jsBin

http://jsbin.com/icaluy/37/edit#preview

Comment: Usman click on csstdgreen make that yellow is 100% correct but i dont want to change html.i have to change css green to yellow using same html which i did in jsbin (:

Comment: See i giving u exmple when i click on jary then i have to make whole jerry block yellow see like this http://jsbin.com/eritud/edit#javascript,html,live How can i do that like same for john and jack

Comment: you can't achieve what you want with your given HTML cz your Block element let say John is not enclosed in a single element like in a single td...thts why i change your HTML to enclosed every block in a TD and then put csstdyellow class on it....i am sure you will get my point....

Comment: look shahid solution he do but change tr css